# COPY /Z equivalent in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting, command-line-interface

I'm trying to get used to using PowerShell whenever I'm tempted to reach for the familiar CMD command line that I've known and come to not-quite-love over a couple of decades. I'm starting to internalize Copy-Item, but one of the things I really miss when copying large files is the /Z argument. If you're not familiar with the /Z argument, it adds a quick progress indicator (see below). For small files, it's completely unnecessary, but it is a sanity saver when copying huge files, especially over a slow network.

[image: COPY /Z]

Is there anything comparable to COPY /Z in PowerShell that doesn't involve lots of code? I'm hoping for something as easy an memorable as a simple argument or maybe a pipable cmdlet along the lines of:
`Copy-Item -Path "C:\Source\File.exe" -Destination "C:\Destination\" | Show-Progress`

Am I out of luck, or does something like this already exist?

Comment: ;-}  Us legacy folks still hanging in there.  ;-} This is why the Progress cmdlets exist. ```Get-Help -Name Write-Progress -Detail``` or examples ```Get-Help - Name Write-Progress -Examples```. Also, just use your favorite search engine to search for 'PowerShell progress bars'

Comment: If you're copying huge files over a slow network I'd argue that you don't want `copy` in the first place, nor any PowerShell equivalent cmdlet -- use `robocopy`. For single files the syntax is a bit clunky (since it works by source and target *directories*, so you have to specify the file name as a filter) but its speed and retry features more than make up for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While *some* PowerShell cmdlets support progress displays, [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) does *not*.

- For those that do support progress displays, such as [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest), the logic is usually *reversed*. Progress is shown *by default*, and must be *silenced on demand*, with `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'`
- While PowerShell offers the [`Write-Progress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress) cmdlet for creating your own progress displays, this won't help you here, as you cannot track the *internal* progress of a *single* object being processed by another command.

However, you can simply call `cmd.exe`s internal `copy` command from PowerShell, via `cmd /c`:

```
cmd /c copy /z C:\Source\File.exe C:\Destination\
```

Note:

- As [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) points out, consider using [`robocopy.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) instead (which you can equally call from PowerShell) - see his comment on the question for details.

Comment: While calling CMD from PoSh feels a bit like cheating, it technically fits the requirement and it definately works.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @AlexPixley. I wouldn't worry about cheating: while it's usually preferable to use PowerShell-native commands, calling external programs is a core function of any shell, even though in this case the external program happens to be a shell as well. In short: there are two good reasons to call external programs: if they offer functionality that isn't / isn't readily available in PowerShell or if they perform a certain task significantly faster.